# Where are the Terminal's Profile Preferences in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal, rvm

I am trying to setup [RVM](https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm) on Ubuntu 20.04. In the guide it says to open the preferences panel on terminal. When I open preferences, only default appears. but when I click on that, different options appear and I cannot find the preferences referenced at Github.

[image]

Comment: That was the correct answer. It's working now

Comment: Consider accepting the correct answer by clicking on the gray check mark ✔ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will mark the problem as solved, and help others find the accepted solution.

Answer (score 5):

The following is for Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop

1. Open a terminal
2. Click on the Burger Menu ≡ and select Preferences

   [image]
3. Go to `Unnamed`

   If you have just the default preferences config, it will be labeled **Unnamed** in the left panel. If you have a profile called **Default** you should see it here and use that instead.

   [image]
4. Select the **Command** tab on the top. Then check the **Run command as a login shell** box.

Comment: Side note: gnome-terminal up to 3.26 used to have two separate "Preferences" and "Profile Preferences" window, as shown on the RVM page. gnome-terminal 3.28, which appeared in Ubuntu 18.04 (i.e. almost 4 years old) merged them into a single Preferences window, listing the profiles on the left hand sidebar.